# How to create empty constructor for data class in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 10+ variables declared in Kotlin data class, and I would like to create an empty constructor for it like how we typically do in Java.

Data class:

```
data class Activity(
    var updated_on: String,
    var tags: List<String>,
    var description: String,
    var user_id: List<Int>,
    var status_id: Int,
    var title: String,
    var created_at: String,
    var data: HashMap<*, *>,
    var id: Int,
    var counts: LinkedTreeMap<*, *>,
)
```

Expected usage:

```
val activity =  Activity();
activity.title = "New Computer"
sendToServer(activity)
```

But the data class requires all arguments to be passed while creating a constructor. How can we simplify this like the Java POJO class constructor?

```
val activity =  Activity(null,null,null,null,null,"New Computer",null,null,null,null)
sendToServer(activity)
```

Answer (score 364, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1. Assign a default value to each [primary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) parameter:

   ```
   data class Activity(
       var updated_on: String = "",
       var tags: List<String> = emptyList(),
       var description: String = "",
       var user_id: List<Int> = emptyList(),
       var status_id: Int = -1,
       var title: String = "",
       var created_at: String = "",
       var data: HashMap<*, *> = hashMapOf<Any, Any>(),
       var id: Int = -1,
       var counts: LinkedTreeMap<*, *> = LinkedTreeMap<Any, Any>()
   )
   ```
2. Declare [a secondary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#secondary-constructors) that has no parameters:

   ```
   data class Activity(
       var updated_on: String,
       var tags: List<String>,
       var description: String,
       var user_id: List<Int>,
       var status_id: Int,
       var title: String,
       var created_at: String,
       var data: HashMap<*, *>,
       var id: Int,
       var counts: LinkedTreeMap<*, *>
   ) {
       constructor() : this("", emptyList(), 
                            "", emptyList(), -1, 
                            "", "", hashMapOf<Any, Any>(), 
                            -1, LinkedTreeMap<Any, Any>()
                            )
   }
   ```

If you don't rely on `copy` or `equals` of the `Activity` class or don't use the autogenerated `data class` methods at all you could use regular class like so:

```
class ActivityDto {
    var updated_on: String = "",
    var tags: List<String> = emptyList(),
    var description: String = "",
    var user_id: List<Int> = emptyList(),
    var status_id: Int = -1,
    var title: String = "",
    var created_at: String = "",
    var data: HashMap<*, *> = hashMapOf<Any, Any>(),
    var id: Int = -1,
    var counts: LinkedTreeMap<*, *> = LinkedTreeMap<Any, Any>()
}
```

Not every [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) needs to be a `data class` and vice versa. In fact in my experience I find data classes to be particularly useful in areas that involve some complex business logic.

Comment: Thanks @miensol, Is there any way this can be done using copy fun.  eg. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#copying

Comment: @SaiKiran to use `copy` you need a data class instance. To create it you need to invoke a constructor - and here was the issue.

Comment: I'm using Kotlin 1.1.2 for Android Studio 2.3 and emptyList is not available :/

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't add kotlin to my build.gradle config file.

Comment: Using emptyList will allocate memory? . I things it will be increase the memory usage

Comment: @Muhammadchhota `emptyList` will not repeatedly allocate memory. [It returns a singleton](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.3/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Collections.kt#L77).

Comment: How do I create a setter for this model?

Comment: @Farwa what do you mean by setter? The properties above are declared as `var` meaning mutable.

Comment: I mean how can I assign values to those programmatically?

Comment: Kotlin makes everything difficult to read

Answer (score 106):

If you give **default values to all the fields** - empty constructor is generated automatically by Kotlin.

```
data class User(var id: Long = -1,
                var uniqueIdentifier: String? = null)
```

and you can simply call:

```
val user = User()
```

Comment: if id is auto-generated then how to use?

Comment: Worked for me. For Firebase Chat message : `class FeelComChatMessage (messageText: String = "", messageUser: String = "")`

Comment: @Panchal Amit Who auto-generates id? Room? You should study it's annotations I think.

Answer (score 27):

the modern answer for this should be using Kotlin's `no-arg compiler plugin` which creates a non argument construct code for classic apies [more about here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/no-arg-plugin.html)

simply you have to add the plugin class path in build.gradle project level

```
    dependencies {
    ....

    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:1.4.10"

    ....
    }
```

then configure your annotation to generate the `no-arg` constructor

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-noarg"

noArg {
      annotation("your.path.to.annotaion.NoArg")
      invokeInitializers = true
}
```

then define your annotation file `NoArg.kt`

```
 @Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
 @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
 annotation class NoArg
```

finally in any data class you can simply use your own annotation

```
@NoArg
data class SomeClass( val datafield:Type , ...   )
```

I used to create my own `no-arg` constructor as the accepted answer , which i got  by search but then this plugin released or something and I found it way cleaner .

Comment: For those using kotlin dsl for gradle, define the plugin via:

    `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg") version "1.5.31"`

Comment: Thank you for writing down this solution! This turned out to be the best workaround for a serialisation issue I ran into with fasterxml/jackson when updating Kotlin from 1.5.3 to 1.6.0, until the dependency is fixed

Comment: it says it can be called only by using reflection

Answer (score 19):

Along with @miensol answer, let me add some details:

If you want a Java-visible empty constructor using data classes, you need to define it explicitely.

Using default values + constructor specifier is quite easy:

```
data class Activity(
    var updated_on: String = "",
    var tags: List<String> = emptyList(),
    var description: String = "",
    var user_id: List<Int> = emptyList(),
    var status_id: Int = -1,
    var title: String = "",
    var created_at: String = "",
    var data: HashMap<*, *> = hashMapOf<Any, Any>(),
    var id: Int = -1,
    var counts: LinkedTreeMap<*, *> = LinkedTreeMap<Any, Any>()
) {
    constructor() : this(title = "") // this constructor is an explicit
                                     // "empty" constructor, as seen by Java.
}
```

This means that with this trick you can now serialize/deserialize this object with the standard Java serializers (Jackson, Gson etc).

Comment: The last commend is wrong. At least for the Gson serializer, in fact, Gson uses the unsafe mechanism to create objects and it will not call your constructor. I have just answered a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390294/what-should-i-do-if-i-dont-want-a-devired-class-call-base-classs-constructor-i/59393841#59393841

Answer (score 11):

If you give a default value to each primary constructor parameter:

```
data class Item(var id: String = "",
            var title: String = "",
            var condition: String = "",
            var price: String = "",
            var categoryId: String = "",
            var make: String = "",
            var model: String = "",
            var year: String = "",
            var bodyStyle: String = "",
            var detail: String = "",
            var latitude: Double = 0.0,
            var longitude: Double = 0.0,
            var listImages: List<String> = emptyList(),
            var idSeller: String = "")
```

and from the class where the instances you can call it without arguments or with the arguments that you have that moment

```
var newItem = Item()

var newItem2 = Item(title = "exampleTitle",
            condition = "exampleCondition",
            price = "examplePrice",
            categoryId = "exampleCategoryId")
```

Comment: how do we handle this when we pass the context value.

Answer (score 10):

### Non-empty secondary constructor for data class in Kotlin:

```
data class ChemicalElement(var name: String,
                           var symbol: String,
                           var atomicNumber: Int,
                           var atomicWeight: Double,
                           var nobleMetal: Boolean?) {

    constructor(): this("Silver", "Ag", 47, 107.8682, true)
}

fun main() {
    var chemicalElement = ChemicalElement()
    println("RESULT: ${chemicalElement.symbol} means ${chemicalElement.name}")
    println(chemicalElement)
}

// RESULT: Ag means Silver

// ChemicalElement(name=Silver, symbol=Ag, atomicNumber=47, 
//                 atomicWeight=107.8682, nobleMetal=true)
```

### Empty secondary constructor for data class in Kotlin:

```
data class ChemicalElement(var name: String,
                           var symbol: String,
                           var atomicNumber: Int,
                           var atomicWeight: Double,
                           var nobleMetal: Boolean?) {

    constructor(): this("", "", -1, 0.0, null)
}

fun main() {
    var chemicalElement = ChemicalElement()
    println(chemicalElement)
}

// ChemicalElement(name=, symbol=, atomicNumber=-1, 
//                 atomicWeight=0.0, nobleMetal=null)
```

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors)

> NOTE: On the JVM, if all of the parameters of the primary constructor
>   have default values, the compiler will generate an additional
>   parameterless constructor which will use the default values. This
>   makes it easier to use Kotlin with libraries such as Jackson or JPA
>   that create class instances through parameterless constructors.

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest to modify the primary constructor and add a **default value** to each parameter:

```
data class Activity(
    var updated_on: String = "",
    var tags: List<String> = emptyList(),
    var description: String = "",
    var user_id: List<Int> = emptyList(),
    var status_id: Int = -1,
    var title: String = "",
    var created_at: String = "",
    var data: HashMap<*, *> = hashMapOf<Any, Any>(),
    var id: Int = -1,
    var counts: LinkedTreeMap<*, *> = LinkedTreeMap<Any, Any>()
)
```

You can also make values nullable by adding `?` and then you can assing `null`:

```
data class Activity(
    var updated_on: String? = null,
    var tags: List<String>? = null,
    var description: String? = null,
    var user_id: List<Int>? = null,
    var status_id: Int? = null,
    var title: String? = null,
    var created_at: String? = null,
    var data: HashMap<*, *>? = null,
    var id: Int? = null,
    var counts: LinkedTreeMap<*, *>? = null
)
```

In general, it is a good practice to avoid nullable objects - write the code in the way that we don't need to use them. Non-nullable objects are one of the advantages of Kotlin compared to Java. Therefore, **the first option above is preferable**.

Both options will give you the desired result:

```
val activity = Activity()
activity.title = "New Computer"
sendToServer(activity)
```