# Kotlin data class + Gson: optional field

Tags: kotlin, gson

I have the following data class in Kotlin:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class RouteGroup(
    @SerializedName("name") var name: String,
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Int
)
```

Sometimes I need to create an object with both fields, sometimes with only one of them.

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

This is not the duplicate of this question: [Can Kotlin data class have more than one constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44391468/6934058)
That question shows how to set a default value for a field. But in my case, I don't need to serialize the field with the default value. I want a field to be serialized only when I explicitly assign a value to it.

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/creating-multiple-constructors-for-data-classes-in-kotlin-32ad27e58cac
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391468/can-kotlin-data-class-have-more-than-one-constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is easy you have to use the nullable operator

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class RouteGroup @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @SerializedName("name") var name: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Int? = null
)
```

Comment: Ok, so when I initialize the object I do it like: `new RouteGroup("my name", null)` or add a new constructor for the `name` field only and set `null` as a default value for an `id` field?

It works like this. But I'm just afraid that if I would have a bigger DTO, then I would need to create constructors for every possible combination of passed fields.

Comment: you can set them as default with null so you will not need another constructor

Comment: Set default with null like this? `data class RouteGroup (@SerializedName("name") var name: String? = null, @SerializedName("id") var id: Int? = null)` If I do so, then I get a compilation error when initializing an object with `new RouteGroup("my name")`. The compilation error is: _Cannot resolve constructor 'RouteGroup(java.lang.String)'_

Comment: not even like that 
`new RouteGroup(name="my name")`

Comment: It doesn't compile for me with this declaration as well. I'm creating this object in a Java class. Can it be the case?

Comment: use the annotation @JvmOverloads

Answer (score 1):

You may need something like this:

```
sealed class RouteGroup

data class RouteGroupWithName(
    @SerializedName("name") var name: String
) : RouteGroup()

data class RouteGroupWithId(
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Int
) : RouteGroup()

data class RouteGroupWithNameAndId(
    @SerializedName("name") var name: String,
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Int
) : RouteGroup()
```

EDIT 1:

Or you can use nullable fields and named parameters like this:

```
data class RouteGroup(
    @SerializedName("name") var name: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Int? = null
)

val routeGroupWithName = RouteGroup(name = "example")
val routeGroupWithId = RouteGroup(id = 2)
val routeGroupWithNameAndId = RouteGroup(id = 2, name = "example")
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a good solution. Even with a small number of fields, the number of possible combinations for a data class grows very fast.

Comment: Why don't you just use nullable values.

Comment: In Kotlin, classes are cheap, for generic data classes it's okay to inherit, but you can't without making the class open as in Kotlin by default everything is final.