# Kotlin, how to use getParcelable to keep state across rotation?

Tags: android, kotlin, onsaveinstancestate

I'm trying to use parcelable to maintain state when rotating my device.

```
val VehiclesParcelable = VehiclesModel()

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
    outState.putParcelable(KEY, VehiclesParcelable)
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        savedInstanceState.getParcelable<VehiclesModel>(KEY)
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to use the `getParcelable`, it says it's deprecated, if I try to use the newer version (that says I need to include the class?) `getParcelable(KEY, VehiclesModel)` I get "type mismatch".

I'm pretty sure I'm putting in the second argument incorrectly.

How do I use the new version? All I find about it just use it like I did in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't figure out how to use the getParcelable, it says it's deprecated

As of API level 33, the one-argument [`getParcelable (String key)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#getParcelable(java.lang.String)) is deprecated. Starting from API level 33, you need to include the class as a second argument using the two-argument version [`getParcelable (String key, Class<T> clazz)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#getParcelable(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E))

In Kotlin, the [KClass formula](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/) is used to represent a class, but to get a Java Class instance corresponding to a given KClass instance, extend that with ".java" suffix ([documentation reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.html)). This would be in your model "**VehiclesModel::class.java**".

So, to fix the deprecation after API level 33:

```
override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) // API 33
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        savedInstanceState.getParcelable<VehiclesModel>(KEY)
    else
        savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY, VehiclesModel::class.java)
}
```

**Side notes:**

- The condition `if(savedInstanceState != null)` has been removed because the `savedInstanceState` argument is not nullable.
- The `VehiclesModel` model class is typically a data class, and that expects a constructor with one argument at least, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44397706/9851608). So, you need to fix that in `val VehiclesParcelable = VehiclesModel()` statement.
- ViewModel would be a typical tool instead of `onSaveInstaceState()` if you just want to survive configuration changes.

---

**Update for the bountied part**

> how would you solve the bountied part? I'm using Java so I'm using if (savedInstanceState != null) instead of a method onRestoreInstanceState.

Even if you're using Java, the the `savedInstanceState` is annotated with @NonNull; so it shouldn't be null; instead you'd worry if the `getParcelable()` returned null in case the key was wrong.

The code in java, you'd use `Bitmap.class` instead of the OP `VehiclesModel`:

```
String KEY = "stateOfImageView";

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    savedInstanceState.putParcelable(KEY, bitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    Bitmap bitmap;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) // API 33
        bitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY);
    else
        bitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY, Bitmap.class);
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Thank you for the answer, And how would you solve the bountied part? I'm using Java so I'm using `if (savedInstanceState != null)` instead of a method `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Comment: @xralf Please check the updated answer, hopefully it helps

Comment: I have the same warning now. Should I add somewhere @Suppress("DEPRECATION")?

Comment: You could do that if you wish, in java it's `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` but unlike Kotlin, it's not supported to put it anywhere ; you'd do that just before the method declaration; but be sure that it will suppress any single deprecation, so don't do that on a wide range of code... The warning is just because sometimes Android studio couldn't be enough intelligent that you add it within the non deprecated APIs (i.e., before API level 33)