# Retrofit-Vertx with RxJava2 in Kotlin IllegalStateException message == null

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, vert.x, rx-java2

I'm building a very simple application in Kotlin with Vertx and RxJava 2 (RxKotlin), using Kovert REST framework and Retrofit. I have retrofit-vertx adapter and the RxJava2 Retrofit adapter. I can return an arbitrary list from my `listUndergroundStations()` method, but whenever I try to load from the remote API I get the following error:

```
Jun 23, 2017 2:16:29 PM uk.amb85.rxweb.api.UndergroundRestController
SEVERE: HTTP CODE 500 - /api/underground/stations - java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: message == null
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: message == null
    at io.reactivex.internal.util.ExceptionHelper.wrapOrThrow(ExceptionHelper.java:45)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.BlockingMultiObserver.blockingGet(BlockingMultiObserver.java:91)
    at io.reactivex.Single.blockingGet(Single.java:2148)
    at uk.amb85.rxweb.api.UndergroundRestController$listUndergroundStations$1.invoke(UndergroundRestController.kt:35)
    at uk.amb85.rxweb.api.UndergroundRestController$listUndergroundStations$1.invoke(UndergroundRestController.kt:13)
    at nl.komponents.kovenant.TaskPromise$wrapper$1.invoke(promises-jvm.kt:138)
    at nl.komponents.kovenant.TaskPromise$wrapper$1.invoke(promises-jvm.kt:130)
    at nl.komponents.kovenant.NonBlockingDispatcher$ThreadContext.run(dispatcher-jvm.kt:327)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: message == null
    at com.julienviet.retrofit.vertx.VertxCallFactory$VertxCall.lambda$enqueue$0(VertxCallFactory.java:90)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryFail(FutureImpl.java:170)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.handleException(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:270)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.handleEnd(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:259)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.ClientConnection.handleResponseEnd(ClientConnection.java:361)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.ClientHandler.doMessageReceived(ClientHandler.java:80)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.ClientHandler.doMessageReceived(ClientHandler.java:38)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.VertxHttpHandler.lambda$channelRead$0(VertxHttpHandler.java:71)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:335)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:193)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.VertxHttpHandler.channelRead(VertxHttpHandler.java:71)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:122)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1228)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1039)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:642)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:565)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:479)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: message == null
    at okhttp3.Response$Builder.build(Response.java:431)
    at com.julienviet.retrofit.vertx.VertxCallFactory$VertxCall.lambda$null$1(VertxCallFactory.java:109)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl$BodyHandler.notifyHandler(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:301)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.lambda$bodyHandler$0(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:193)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.handleEnd(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:257)
    ... 36 more
```

I can't for the life of me work out what is causing the `IllegalStateException` and have googled it to death. I don't think it's Rx related because I get the same error if I make the method return `Observable<List<UndergroundLine>>` or even get rid of Rx entirely and return `Call<List<UndergroundLine>>` (adjusting the controller accordingly). However, beyond that, I'm beating my head against a wall! Is anyone able to point out the error of my ways (besides putting a cushion under my head)?

Main Verticle:

```
class ApiVerticle : AbstractVerticle() {

    override fun start(startFuture: Future<Void>?) {
        // Initialise injection.
        configureKodein()

        val apiRouter = configureRouter(vertx)

        vertx.createHttpServer()
                .requestHandler { apiRouter.accept(it) }
                .listen(8080)
    }

    private fun configureKodein() {
        Kodein.global.addImport(Kodein.Module {
            import(TflUndergroundService.module)
        })
    }

    private fun configureRouter(vertx: Vertx): Router {
        val apiMountPoint = "api"
        val routerInit = fun Router.() {
            bindController(UndergroundRestController(), apiMountPoint)
        }
        val router = Router.router(vertx) initializedBy { router ->
            router.routerInit()
        }
        return router
    }
}
```

TflService:

```
interface TflService {
    @GET("/Line/Mode/tube")
    fun getAllUndergroundLines(): Observable<UndergroundLine>

    @GET("/Line/{lineName}/StopPoints")
    fun getStationsForUndergroundLine(
            @Path("lineName") lineName: String
    ): Observable<UndergroundStation>

    @GET("/Line/{lineName}/Arrivals?stopPointId={stationNaptanId")
    fun getArrivalsFor(
            @Path("lineName") lineName: String,
            @Path("stationNaptanId") stationNaptanId: String
    ) : Observable<Arrival>
}

data class UndergroundLine(val id: String, val name: String)
data class UndergroundStation(val naptanId: String, val commonName: String)
data class Arrival(
        val platformName: String,
        val towards: String,
        val currentLocation: String,
        val expectedArrival: LocalDateTime)

object TflUndergroundService {
    val module = Kodein.Module {
        val vertx: Vertx = Vertx.currentContext().owner()
        val client: HttpClient = vertx.createHttpClient()

        val jacksonMapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        jacksonMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

        val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.tfl.gov.uk/")
                .callFactory(VertxCallFactory(client))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createAsync())
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(jacksonMapper))
                .build()

        val tflService: TflService = retrofit.create(TflService::class.java)

        bind<TflService>() with instance(tflService)
    }
}
```

ApiKeySecured (Just requires "appid" to be a parameter):

```
class ApiKeySecured(private val routingContext: RoutingContext) : KodeinGlobalAware {
    val user: String = routingContext.request().getParam("appid") ?: throw HttpErrorUnauthorized()
}
```

The offending REST controller (in Kovert, `Promise`'s are executed on Vertx worker thread):

```
class UndergroundRestController(val undergroundService: TflService = Kodein.global.instance()) {
    fun ApiKeySecured.listUndergroundStations(): Promise<List<UndergroundLine>, Exception> {
        //TODO: This is blocking, fix it!??
        return task {
            undergroundService
                    .getAllUndergroundLines()
                    .doOnError { println(it) }
                    .toList()
                    .blockingGet()
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
mainClassName = "io.vertx.core.Launcher"
def mainVerticleName = "uk.amb85.rxweb.verticles.ApiVerticle"
def configurationFile = "conf/development.json"

run {
    args = ["run",
            mainVerticleName,
            "--launcher-class=$mainClassName",
            "-conf $configurationFile"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your main class?

Comment: `ApiVerticle` is configured in Gradle to be the main class.

Comment: so could you please add that part of configuration to the question?

Comment: @ledniov That's been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with `retrofit-vertx` you are using. `OkHttp3`'s `ResponseBuilder` requires `message` to be not null, but `VertxCallFactory` doesn't set it.

It's fixed in the latest version, but as it's still in development, you have to use snapshot:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.julienviet:retrofit-vertx:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT'

}
```

Switching to snapshot dependency fixes the issue you mention in your question, but there's an issue with json mapping, which can be easily fixed by switching code from:

```
@GET("/Line/Mode/tube")
fun getAllUndergroundLines(): Observable<UndergroundLine>
```

to:

```
@GET("/Line/Mode/tube")
fun getAllUndergroundLines(): Observable<List<UndergroundLine>>
```

And updating your data classes to have default empty constructor to let `Jackson` instantiate using reflection:

```
data class UndergroundLine(var id: String = "", var name: String = "")
```

[More on emtpy default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37874665/1126831) for data classes.

But it's another question related to how to parse response from API you're using to `Observable` and should be asked if you don't find a workaround.

Comment: Thanks. I'd noticed the need to return an `Observable<List<...>>` when I tried not using retrofit-vertx. I'll give the snapshot a try and see where I go from there.

Comment: The version 1.0.2 that fixes the bug and updates to Vert.x 3.4.2 is now release