# In Kotlin, how do you declare a data class with zero constructor parameters?

Tags: kotlin

Say I want to declare a simple algebraic datatype for integer lists:

```
sealed class IntList
data class Cons(val head: Int, val tail: IntList): IntList()
data class Nil() : IntList()
```

However, the last declaration results in an error

> Data class must have at least one primary constructor parameter

1. Why is this limitation present? Looking at the documentation, there seems to be no good technical reasons for requiring data class constructors to be non-nullary.
2. Is it possible to express nullary constructors without having to write lots of boilerplate code? If I change the last declaration to something like

   ```
   sealed class Nil() : IntList()
   ```

   then I lose the free implementations of `hashCode()` and `equals()` that come for free with `data class` declarations.

**EDIT**

Alex Filatov gave a nice short solution below. Obviously, you never need more than one instance of `Nil`, so we can just define a singleton object

```
object Nil : IntList()
```

However, what would we do if our lists were parameterized by a type parameter? That is, now the first two lines of our definition would be

```
sealed class List<A>
data class Cons<A>(val head: A, val tail: List<A>): List<A>()
```

We cannot declare a polymorphic singleton `Nil` object which derives from `List<A>` for any `A`, since we have to provide a concrete type for `A` at the time of declaration. The solution (taken from [this post](http://developers-club.com/posts/268463/)) is to declare `A` as a covariant type parameter and declare `Nil` as a subtype of `List<Nothing>` as follows:

```
sealed class List<out A>
data class Cons<A>(val head: A, val tail: List<A>): List<A>()
object Nil : List<Nothing>()
```

This allows us to write

```
val xs: List<Int> = Cons(1, Cons(2, Nil))
val ys: List<Char> = Cons('a', Cons('b', Nil))
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873995/how-to-create-empty-constructor-for-data-class-in-kotlin-android But it seems not fit your situation.

Comment: Also, "_Note that properties that aren’t declared in the primary constructor don’t take part in the equality checks and hashcode calculation._"

Comment: @UlrikRasmussen Why do you need `hashCode()` and `equals()` if the class should not contain any field?

Comment: For if I want to compare two lists. But this is only an issue when there can be distinct instances of Nil. By representing Nil as a singleton, the default implementations of these methods will suffice

Comment: @UlrikRasmussen Please post your edit as answer! :) answers should not be in the question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because `data class` without data doesn't make sense. Use `object` for singletons:

```
object Nil : IntList()
```

Comment: This worked well for my use case, which was a simple algebraic datatype without type parameters. However, how would I go about representing nullary constructors for parameterized types? For example, let's generalize to `sealed class List<A>` with cons constructor `data class Cons<A>(val h:A, val t:List<A>): List<A>()`. I cannot declare a polymorphic object `object Nil<A> : List<A>()`

Comment: I found a solution and have updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a usual class

```
class Nil : IntList()
```

and implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` yourself.

A data class without fields does not make any sense, since its job is to represent data.

---

Or: You can use an object class (as [Alex Filatov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4268663/alex-filatov) said) which is a single instance class. Since, you don't need a state for each single `Nil` instance, they can share a single one.