# How to debug HttpMessageNotReadableException?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a DTO object like this:

```
data class ClientDto(
        var uuid: String,
        var ip: String,
        var lastSeen: Date? = Date()
) {
    internal fun toEntity() = Client(uuid=uuid, ip=ip, lastSeen=Date())
}
```

... and a controller like this:

```
@RestController
internal class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var service : ClientService

    @GetMapping("/clients")
    internal fun getClients() =  service.findAll()

    @PostMapping("/clients")
    internal fun postClient(@RequestBody client: ClientDto) = service.add(client)
}
```

Now I post with httpie something like this:

```
http POST localhost:8080/clients uuid=my-uuid ip=192.123.31:8080
```

And get:

```
{
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of awesome.discovery.domain.dto.ClientDto: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of awesome.discovery.domain.dto.ClientDto: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@71c6ae97; line: 1, column: 2]",
    "path": "/clients",
    "status": 400,
    "timestamp": 1519587678605
}
```

1. What is wrong with this post?
2. More importantly how can I debug this, e.g. know what it tries and how to get to understand where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- Your DTO needs to provide a default constructor (empty constructor with no arguments). It's what the error says

2- Spring configures Jackson to use reflection for automatic deserialization of JSON according to the type of the `RequestParam`. You can customize this behaviour implementing `JsonDeserializer`. If you want to debug you can put a breakpoint on the method annotated with `PostMapping`

Comment: I did understand that kotlins Default constructor is set like I did in data classes.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Here is an answer regarding visisibillity of the default constructor in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47530515/333566

Comment: That's right, I don't use kotlin but I've had this similar issue with project lombok's `Data` and `Value` annotations