# What should I do if I don't want a devired class call base class's constructor in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, constructor

Is there any way to create an instance of `Derived` but not call the constructor of `Base`?

```
open class Base(p: Int)

class Derived(p: Int) : Base(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually can do it

```
import sun.misc.Unsafe

open class Base(p: Int){
    init {
        println("Base")
    }
}

class Derived(p: Int) : Base(p){
    init {
        println("Derived")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val unsafe = Unsafe::class.java.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe").apply {
        isAccessible = true
    }.get(null) as Unsafe

    val x = unsafe.allocateInstance(Derived::class.java)

    println("X = $x")
}
```

But don't, this solution is a low-level mechanism that was designed to be used only by the core Java library and not by standard users. You will break the logic of OOP if you use it.

Comment: Cảm ơn by the way.

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible. The constructor of the derived class has to call (any) constructor of the base class in order to initialise the content(fields) of the base class.

This is also the same case in Java. Just that the default constructor is called by default (if no parameters are provided in the constructor), but if you have to choose between constructors with parameters, you always have to call them explicitly, because you have to choose which values to pass into the constructor.

Comment: Indeed.  The whole point of a constructor is to set up each instance, to get it into a consistent state.  Both Java and Kotlin ensure that a constructor is always called (at each level), so that the whole object starts off in a consistent state.

Answer (score 0):

You must always call a constructor of a super-class to ensure that the foundation of the class is initialized. But you can work around your issue by providing a no-arg constructor in the base class. Something like this:

```
open class Base(p: Int?){
    val p: Int? = p
    constructor(): this(null)
}

class Derived(p: Int) : Base()
```

The way you handle which constructor of the base class is default and which parameters are nullable, etc. will depend highly on the specific case.