# InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity when making an Entity field NOT nullable in Kotlin

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a Project Entity (as shown below). When I try to change

```
var fullName: String?= null
```

to:

```
var fullName: String,
```

I suddenly get an InstantiationException from Hibernate:

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:
```

Before this there were no problems. What could be going wrong? Here is the Entity class:

```
package no.inmeta.ris.project.model.entity

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
data class Project (

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    var id : UUID? = null,

    var fullName: String,

    var shortName: String? = null,

    var prevRefId: String? = null,

    var startDate: Date? = null,

    var endDate: Date?  = null,

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Associated_Projects",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "associated_project")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "second_associated_project") ])
    var associatedProjects: List<Project?> = mutableListOf(),

    var shortDescription: String? = null,

    var summary: String?  = null,

    var url: String? = null,

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Project_Types",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "project_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "type_id") ])
    var type: List<Type?> = mutableListOf()
    )
```

Comment: Hey @Nora , I think  default constructor is Missing. have u added that ?

Answer (score 0):

Provide a default value for fullName parameter or keep it nullable.

In your code, it does not have default value, so in generated Java bytecode Project class won't have a constructor without parameters - it will need at least 1 parameter to initialize fullName field.

Comment: I am creating an API and trying to avoid any default value. at the same time I don't want fullName to be null because it is a required field

Comment: Hibernate requires a default constructor. Default constructor is a constructor without parameters. If you want Kotlin to generate default constructor for data class, you have to set default parameters for every property declared in its primary constructor.

Comment: Look at the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873995/how-to-create-empty-constructor-for-data-class-in-kotlin-android

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a default constructor. You can make this private, if you dont want to expose it outside this class:

```
package no.inmeta.ris.project.model.entity

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
data class Project (

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    var id : UUID? = null,

    var fullName: String,

    var shortName: String? = null,

    var prevRefId: String? = null,

    var startDate: Date? = null,

    var endDate: Date?  = null,

    private constructor()

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Associated_Projects",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "associated_project")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "second_associated_project") ])
    var associatedProjects: List<Project?> = mutableListOf(),

    var shortDescription: String? = null,

    var summary: String?  = null,

    var url: String? = null,

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Project_Types",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "project_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "type_id") ])
    var type: List<Type?> = mutableListOf()
    )
```