# How to create custom jsonb mapper for PostgreSQL and Hibernate in Kotlin?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, jsonb

I went through available articles: [1](https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/), [2](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/postgresqls-jsonb-type-mapping-using-hibernate/), [3](https://notes.kartashov.com/2016/01/29/adding-jsonb-support-to-hibernate/).

All of the articles nail down to the following options:

- Register custom `PostgreSQL95Dialect` which has `jsonb` type
- Implement Hibernate's `UserType`interface with custom mapping
- Annotate `Entity` with `@TypeDef` of custom implementation
- Define in application.properties custom dialect

If all of the above is done, code is supposed to work. In my case I bump into mysterious `Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.example.Book.header type: com.example.hibernate.BookHeaderType` which I don't understand how to debug further.

My `JsonbType` abstract class:

```
abstract class JsonbType : UserType {

    override fun hashCode(p0: Any?): Int {
        return p0!!.hashCode()
    }

    override fun deepCopy(p0: Any?): Any {
        return try {
            val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            val oos = ObjectOutputStream(bos)
            oos.writeObject(p0)
            oos.flush()
            oos.close()
            bos.close()
            val bais = ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray())
            ObjectInputStream(bais).readObject()
        } catch (ex: ClassNotFoundException) {
            throw HibernateException(ex)
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            throw HibernateException(ex)
        }
    }

    override fun replace(p0: Any?, p1: Any?, p2: Any?): Any {
        return deepCopy(p0)
    }

    override fun equals(p0: Any?, p1: Any?): Boolean {
        return p0 == p1
    }

    override fun assemble(p0: Serializable?, p1: Any?): Any {
        return deepCopy(p0)
    }

    override fun disassemble(p0: Any?): Serializable {
        return deepCopy(p0) as Serializable
    }

    override fun nullSafeSet(p0: PreparedStatement?, p1: Any?, p2: Int, p3: SharedSessionContractImplementor?) {
        if (p1 == null) {
            p0?.setNull(p2, Types.OTHER)
            return
        }
        try {
            val mapper = ObjectMapper()
            val w = StringWriter()
            mapper.writeValue(w, p1)
            w.flush()
            p0?.setObject(p2, w.toString(), Types.OTHER)
        } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to convert Jsonb to String: " + ex.message, ex)
        }
    }

    override fun nullSafeGet(p0: ResultSet?, p1: Array<out String>?, p2: SharedSessionContractImplementor?, p3: Any?): Any {
        val cellContent = p0?.getString(p1?.get(0))
        return try {
            val mapper = ObjectMapper()
            mapper.readValue(cellContent?.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")), returnedClass())
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to convert String to Jsonb: " + ex.message, ex)
        }
    }

    override fun isMutable(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun sqlTypes(): kotlin.IntArray? {
        return IntArray(Types.JAVA_OBJECT)
    }
}
```

My concrete class `BookHeaderType` looks:

```
class BookHeaderType : JsonbType() {

    override fun returnedClass(): Class<BookBody> {
        return BookBody::class.java
    }

}
```

`CustomPostgreSQLDialect.kt`:

```
class CustomPostgreSQLDialect : PostgreSQL95Dialect {

    constructor(): super() {
        this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonb")
    }
}
```

`Book.kt` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@TypeDefs(
        TypeDef(name = "BookHeaderType", typeClass = BookHeaderType::class)
)
data class Book(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
        val id: Long,

        @Column(name = "header", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "jsonb")
        @Type(type = "BookHeaderType")
        var header: BookHeader
)
```

`BookHeader.kt` implements Serializable

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class BookHeader(
    var createdAt: OffsetDateTime,
    var createdBy: String
) : Serializable {
    constructor() : this(OffsetDateTime.now(), "test")
}
```

What do I do wrong? Should `jsonb` custom type be created differently in `Kotlin`?

Comment: Maybe also post your table definition.

Comment: what is your BookBody?

Comment: Have you solved the issue @DimytroChasovskyi?

Comment: @paranza Yes, I solved. I basically give up on Hibernate and took JdbcTemplate. It didn't worth time-spending. Also, I just Googled this problem again and found [hackish alternative](https://www.javaadvent.com/2017/12/map-json-collections-using-jpa-hibernate.html).

Comment: @paranza Are you still struggling with this issue? Can you add a link to the bootstrapped project that will show an issue, so we can update this question and create answer, so other people can benefit from it as well?

Comment: yes massively and I am not really sure what it is going on. There is a new question I opened with 2 approaches listed (with custom mapper and with hibernate-types): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371808/springbootkotlinpostgres-and-jsonb-org-hibernate-mappingexception-no-dialec?noredirect=1#comment108569814_61371808 BTW, thank you for getting back to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sibling question that has [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371808/springbootkotlinpostgres-and-jsonb-org-hibernate-mappingexception-no-dialec/61458109#answer-61458109)

You would need to use custom types:

pom.xml dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Register Customer PostgreSQL dialect:

```
class CustomPostgreSQLDialect : PostgreSQL95Dialect {
  constructor() : super() {
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonStringType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonBinaryType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType::class.java.name)
    this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeStringType::class.java.name)
  }
}
```

**Option 1:**

Annotate Entity with `jsonb` type and make `jsonb` as `Map<String, Any>`:

```
import com.example.demo.pojo.SamplePojo
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "tests")
@TypeDefs(
        TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType::class),
        TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)
)
data class SampleEntity (
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    val id: Long?,
    val name: String?,

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    var data: Map<String, Any>?
) {

    /**
     * Dependently on use-case this can be done differently:
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873995/how-to-create-empty-constructor-for-data-class-in-kotlin-android
     */
    constructor(): this(null, null, null)
}
```

You would need Pojo to Map serializer/deserializer.

**Option 2:**

Annotate Entity with `jsonb` type and make `jsonb` as `JsonNode?`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "tests")
@TypeDefs(
        TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType::class),
        TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)
)
data class SampleJsonNodeEntity (
        @Id @GeneratedValue
        val id: Long?,
        val name: String?,

        @Type(type = "jsonb")
        @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
        var data: JsonNode?
) {

    /**
     * Dependently on use-case this can be done differently:
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873995/how-to-create-empty-constructor-for-data-class-in-kotlin-android
     */
    constructor(): this(null, null, null)
}
```

You would need custom POJO to JsonNode, assumingly Jackson serializer/deserializer.

**Summary:**

1st option is better when you have a big JSON with one level of indentation.

2nd option is better when you have nested objects in objects data-types.